# I want to use fields of custom compound Address field in Lightning component and controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lookup, lookup-field, compound-fields

I have a custom object Address_book__c,lets say "A" which has differnt custom address fields like shipping_street__c and I have a lookup field from another custom object(say "B") on this "A" object. Now, I want to use/access different field values of the "B" in Lightning component and controller to use values in inputAddress tag. How can I achieve that? Is it even possible? Or Do I need to create these fields separately on object A as well but that will defeat the purpose of having a lookup.

```
<lightning:inputAddress aura:id="bOrder"
                                        addressLabel="Billing Address"
                                        streetLabel="Street"
                                        cityLabel="City"
                                        countryLabel="Country"
                                        provinceLabel="State/Province"
                                        postalCodeLabel="PostalCode"
                                        street="{!if(v.beerOrder.Billing_Same_as_Shipping__c,v.beerOrder.Shipping_Street__c,v.beerOrder.Billing_Street__c)}"
                                        city="{!if(v.beerOrder.Billing_Same_as_Shipping__c,v.beerOrder.Shipping_City__c,v.beerOrder.Billing_City__c)}"
                                        country="{!if(v.beerOrder.Billing_Same_as_Shipping__c,v.beerOrder.Shipping_Country__c,v.beerOrder.Billing_Country__c)}"
                                        province="{!if(v.beerOrder.Billing_Same_as_Shipping__c,v.beerOrder.Shipping_State__c,v.beerOrder.Billing_State__c)}"
                                        postalCode="{!if(v.beerOrder.Billing_Same_as_Shipping__c,v.beerOrder.Shipping_Postal_Code__c,v.beerOrder.Billing_Postal_Code__c)}"
                                        required="{!!v.beerOrder.Billing_Same_as_Shipping__c}"
                                        readonly ="{!v.beerOrder.Billing_Same_as_Shipping__c}"
                                        fieldLevelHelp="Input Billing Address here if different from shipping"
                                        />`
```

Comment: Try using `B.LookupA__r.Shipping_Street__c` and see if that works

Comment: Tried using it Brian but when I tried entering data into the field from UI, it threw some unexpected error and reported to salesforce multiple times. I think we cannot use this. Are you sure about this way?

Comment: I'm not 100%, and I'm not sure what's causing your particular error.  If you edit your post and include some of these details (including the error messages and/or a screenshot) and your attempted solutions, the community can give you some better direction